# Display image on top of page with big 3 + jquery, in FireFox?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

[image]

Would like to bring a single image to the front or on top of the page, when selected.

After searching, it seems there are many plug-ins that support this - but also have a lot of other functionality and overhead I don't need (gallery, support for video, thumbnails, etc.)

Is it possible to just bring a single image on top with basic JavaScript, CSS, HTML and jQuery, specifically in FireFox?

Thank You.

(Please note*: This is an in house product, hence these requirements and constraints.)

Comment: have you tried Modals of bootstrap? http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals

Comment: @JeffRobertDagala: never seen it, let me check it out....(that is one slow link)

Comment: You may also consider jQueryUI dialog()  http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: I think you just need a hidden DIV with a high z-index. Load the image into the DIV, `show()` it, and change the CSS of the main content DIV to get the gray background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very basic example I whipped up. Hopefully good to learn from:

http://jsfiddle.net/v9LTP/2/

```
$('img').click(function(){  //bind a click event handler to images
    var img = $(this).clone().addClass('modal').appendTo($('#blackout')); //clone the clicked image element and add to the blackout div which gives the dark background.
    $('#blackout > #close').click(function(){ //attach click handler to close button
        $('#blackout').fadeOut(function(){ //fade the blackout div
            img.remove(); //remove the image element we cloned, so we can do it again.
        }); 
    });
    $('#blackout').fadeIn(); //show the blackout div
});
```

​

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to just bring a single image ontop with basic JavaScript, CSS, HTML and jQuery, specifically in FireFox?

Yes, it's possible, but the plugins are most of the time an easier implementation. What you are trying to accomplish is something similar to the `light box` effect, but I'll try to give a simple solution based on 4 steps you need to accomplish what you are trying to do:

1. Create an overlay div. This one div will blur or darken your entire page. In the below example it will darken your screen (because it's simpler).
2. Create an div that will be appended to the overlay div and will contain the image you want to show. In the demo below, this div will be `lighter` than the overlay one and will actually have half the width and half the height of your screen.
3. Append a bigger image to your image-div.
4. Add a subtitle to your image based on it's `alt` text.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function()
   {

       var docWidth = $(document).width();
       var docHeight = $(document).height();

       //First Step" Creating the overlay-div and adding opacity to it
       var overlayDiv = "<div id="overlay-div"></div>"
       $("body").append(overlayDiv);
       $("#overlay-div").css("position","absolute", "top","0","left","0","background-color","#000","opacity","0.5", "width", docWidth + "px", "height",docHeight + "px");

       //Second step: Creating the image-div and centering it on the screen

       $("#overlay-div").append("<div id=\"image-div\"></div>");
       $("#image-div").css("position","absolute", "top",docHeight/4 + "px","left",docWidth/4 + "px","background-color","#FFF", "width", docWidth/2, "height",docHeight);

       //Third step: Creating an image to display inside the image-div and centering it

       $("#image-div").append("<img src=\"path/to/your/image\"id=\"zoomed-img\" alt=\"This is a zoomed image\"/>");
       var imgWidth = $("#image-div").width();
       var imgHeight = $("#image-height").height();

       $("#image-div").css("position","absolute", "top","10px","left","10px");

       //Fourth step: Creating a subtitle from the alt text
       var subtitle = "<p id=\"text-subtitle\">" + $("#image-div").attr("alt") + "</p>";

       $("#image-div").append(subtitle);
       $("#text-subtitle").css("position","absolute", "top",imgHeight + 20 + "px","left","10px");


   });
   ```

This function is triggered when your document is ready, and get an arbitrary image. But it's possible to display a different image (with a different subtitle) triggered by a click with a little tweak of the code above.

I had the intention to show you a simple demo that it's feasible to with with a few lines of jQuery/javascript code to create what you want. Of course it's not as pretty as 90% of the effects of the plugins there are around but it may be a start.

I hope it helped. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

For a stupid simple lightbox I've been leveraging http://buckwilson.me/lightboxme/ lately.

Answer (score 1):

Try Modals of Bootstrap.

[JavaScript - Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals)

GitHub source code

[GitHub bootstrap-modal.js](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/js/bootstrap-modal.js)